# Required gclid error when the gclid is present

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am trying to upload offline conversions into Google Adwords, but I am encountering an error on the `$uploadResult = $conversionService->mutate($operations)` call. The error that I am getting is `RequiredError.REQUIRED @ operations[0].operand.conversionGclid` with an identical entry for every operation that I have in the array.

According to the documentation, this error is thrown when a required field is left null, but I know that the field is not null because the following line returns the value:

```
    foreach($opperations as $opp){
        print "Value of opp->gclid : " . $opp->operand->googleClickID . "\n\n";
    }
```

I gather the information using a query, and this is my code to process the results:

```
if($queryResult->rowCount() > 0){
    print "Query returned " . $queryResult->rowCount() . " rows\n\n";

    $operations = array();
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $feed = new OfflineConversionFeed();
        $feed->conversionName = $conversionName;
        $feed->conversionTime = $row['conversion_datetime'];
        $feed->googleClickID = $row['gclid'];

        $operations[] = new OfflineConversionFeedOperation($feed, 'ADD');
    }

    foreach($opperations as $opp){
        print "Value of opp->gclid : " . $opp->operand->googleClickID . "\n\n";
    }

    //Following line throws error------------
    $uploadResult = $conversionService->mutate($operations);
    printf('Upload for %s : %s complete', $user->GetClientCustomerId() , $conversionName);
    return;
}
printf('No records for %s found', $user->GetClientCustomerId());
```

Looking over the samples that are found [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/importing-conversions) and [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201409/AdvancedOperations/UploadOfflineConversions.php), this should work without any issues, but I am getting the `RequiredError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have used wrong field name. You have used ID in capital.

`try this`

$feed = new OfflineConversionFeed();

$feed->googleClickId = $row['gclid'];

`instead of:`

$feed->googleClickID = $row['gclid'];

may be it fixes the issue..

Comment: That did it. I actually got it to work yesterday by using the constructor for it, `new OfflineConversionFeed($row['gclid'],$conversionName,$row['conversion_datetime'])`, but I just tried it with your answer, and it also worked.